# how to gradually turn transparent action bar into solid color as user scrolls down

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

In recent android L apps ( lets say google i/o 2014 app) with material theme we have seen that if there is image view at top (followed by any kind of list), then to begin with the actionbar is transparent, then as the user scrolls down the actionbar gradually becomes solid color.

**2 questions:**
1. does this phenomenon have some name, if yes what is it?
2. how do i code to achieve this in an app for android L or is it default

Comment: You could look at the source code on [github](https://github.com/google/iosched)

Comment: Have a look at http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/

Comment: @Kuno thanks I did see that one and it did give me a good start, but the problem with that is there is no parallax scrolling,I am now looking into Kirill Grouchnikov [post](https://plus.google.com/109890850430878740511/posts/2Z2X3crWBHu)

Answer (score 2):

take a look here : https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

second question : based on my researching until now, we have to implement it by code. it's called Fading action bar. You should install Libraries for developers (Android application) that have a lot of libraries demo.